# List name of controls, which are displayed the same in all browsers?

Tags: .net, asp.net

This question was asked in a Technical interview. I was asked to list the controls which will display the same way in all browsers(IE, Safari, Firefox) without any problems(rendering, positioning.. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Because of how disparate the browser world is, with so many browsers and so many versions of said browsers, there is no possible way to guarantee that anything will show up exactly the same all the time.